# Write contents of ace.js editor to file in Django

Tags: python, django, ace-editor

I am playing around with the idea of editing my Django templates from the server. I know this is a far shot from that but I wrote this bit of code:

```
def editor(request):
  handle=open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'app/code/test.html'), 'r+')
  var=handle.read()
  context = {
    "message": "editor",
    "code": var
  }
  return render(request, 'app/editor.html', context)
```

That reads a file and passes it's contents to the template where ace.js displays it in the editor.

```
  <div id="editor-container">
    <div id="editor">{{code}}</div>
  </div>
```

It displays just fine and I can edit the text, but if I wanted to save my edits, writing them to the file, the button would need to go to a save route because I'm not using ajax, but how would I pass the new version of the document to the view to be written to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you need to have an hidden input. Whenever the contents of the editor are updated, the input is also update. Saving the contents is just now a matter of submitting the form. Here is what I came up with.

First is the html template where the editor is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ace editing</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #editor {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        
        .editor-container {
            position: relative;
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="editor-container">
        <div id="editor">
            {{code}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js"></script>
    <script>
        var editor = ace.edit('editor');
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
        editor.on('change', function() {
            code_hidden_input = document.querySelector('#id_code');
            code_hidden_input.value = editor.getValue();
            console.log(editor.getValue())
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now in your views.py the code will be like the following.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import MyForm
import os
from django.conf import settings

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    form = MyForm()
    handle = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'core/templates/core/test.html'))
    code = handle.read()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['code'])
            # This is the part where you save the code you have
            # edited to some file
    context = {
        'form': MyForm(),
        'code': code
    }
    return render(request, "core/index.html", context)
```

In your forms.py file create a class called `My Form`  like below

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(max_length=10000, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

That's all, note when submiting html using forms you need to sanitize your input.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good solution. I found https://github.com/django-ace/django-ace and it does similar, but it loads ace onto the text input and all of the ace.js options are built into the django form.